# operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (21000,784) (2000,784)

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

1.I just try to calculate the distance between two numpy array

```
 data_partial_test = data_test[:2000,:]
test_lable = label_test

((data_train_set - data_partial_test)**2).sum(axis=1)
print(data_partial_test.shape)
print(data_train_set.shape)
```

2.What should I in order to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
dist = ((data_train_set[:,None,:] - data_partial_test)**2).sum(axis=1)
```

But you are looking at a huge amount of data (245GB).

Comment: well actually data_train_set do have value, could you please tell me why you put None right here?

Comment: This technique is usually called  [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast.html).